# QBChatDialog data is not persistent. How do I make QBChatDialog data persistent?

Tags: ios, quickblox

I created a QuickBlox QBChatDialog as shown below and in the "successBlock" createdDialog.data is null.

In my QuickBlox account I created Custom Object called "DialogInfo" with a field called "ReadOnly" with type String.

I'm using iOS SDK 2.3

Please tell me how to make QBChatDialog data persistent? I expect the "successBlock" createdDialog.data to not be null.

```
QBChatDialog *chatDialog = [QBChatDialog new];
chatDialog.name = @"Chat with Bob, Sam, Garry";
chatDialog.occupantIDs = @[@(55), @(678), @(22)];
chatDialog.type = QBChatDialogTypeGroup;
chatDialog.data = @{@"class_name": @"DialogInfo", @"ReadOnly": @"true"};
[QBRequest createDialog:chatDialog successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBChatDialog *createdDialog) {

} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {

}];
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Here is debug print of variable createDialog inside successBlock. Notice that data is null.

```
Printing description of createdDialog:

ID:5593d441535c127af61111e0                      
Created At:2015-07-01 11:51:29 +0000                      
Room JID:23266_5593d441535c127af61111e0@muc.chat.quickblox.com                      
name:Chat with Bob, Sam, Garry                      
photo:(null)                      
type:2                      
lastMessage:(null)                      
lastMessageDate:(null)                      
occupantIDs:(
3874827
)                      
userID:3874827                      
data:(null)                      
unreadMessagesCount:0                      
lastMessageUserID:0
```

I expect data to be like:

```
@{@"class_name": @"DialogInfo", @"ReadOnly": @"true"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this issue was fixed in iOS SDK v2.4.4 — Oct 12, 2015

From changelog:

> Fixed an issue with custom parameters in
>   createDialog:successBlock:errorBlock: request.

http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#Framework_changelog: